# Plotting multiple curves on a surface

Tags: plotting, visualization

I'm reading about non-euclidean geometry, and I tried to visualize [hyperboloid model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) of hyperbolic geometry using Mathematica.

What I need to do is to accent intersections between hyperboloid $x^2  + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ and various planes.
I've been able to do it using `ContourPlot3D` and `MeshFunctions` in the following
way:

```
gr = ContourPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
  Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 30, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, x]}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Thick]
```

But I would like to visualize multiple plane-hyperboloid intersections in one
picture (they correspond to lines in this model of hyperbolic geometry).
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the alternate functions in your `MeshFunctions` list:

```
gr = ContourPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2},
  Axes -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 30,
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, x], 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 2 x + y]}, 
   Mesh -> {{0.}},
  MeshStyle -> Thick]
```

But be sure to define your `MeshFunctions` such that the `Mesh-> {{0.}}` applies to each.